# Function tag seems to not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a simple "Choose your own adventure" style game in Javascript format, mainly because its simple to write, but I have run into a problem. I am trying to get the javascript to run on page load, but it wont start. I am just left with a blank page.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<title>Dungeons and Dwarves</title>
<script type="text/javascript>
    function begin() {
    alert("Welcome to Dungeons and Dwarves! A free 'Choose Your Own Adventure' game. In this adventure, you will be faced with many decisions, some of which could potentially lead to your death. If you are willing to put your life on the line, and leap forward into a new world and explore the unexplored, press OK to begin.")
    var myAge = prompt("How old are you, adventurer?")
    if (myAge < 18)
    {
        alert("Oh! They start younger and younger every year! You'll be careful out there, wont you?")
    }
    else
    {
        alert("I see you have had some experience with adventures! I wish you the best of luck, not that you will need it!")
    }
}
</script>
<body onload='javascript:begin()'>
</body>
```

Im not sure what I have done wrong here, but I think the function tag isn't working properly. Just the way it looks in Notepad++, that might just be me. Could anyone give me assistance?

I apologise if I have formatted this wrong.

Comment: You've got 2 body tags.  I'm assuming the 1st is meant to be a html tag, which would also need to be closed at the end of the document as well.

Comment: @Archer - you mean `head` tag

Comment: There is a missing quote as well.

Comment: `<body onload='begin()'>`. And add semicolons!

Comment: @johnnycardy He's missing that as well.  Look at the very first tag - it's a body tag.  There's no html tag.

Comment: Thank you all! A great group effort! I missed so much and I will never write code while half asleep again.

Answer (score 4):

The browser thinks your JavaScript is not JavaScript (but some other, unknown kind of script):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
```

You omitted the second `"` from the type attribute.

As of HTML 5, the `type` attribute may be omited if you are using JavaScript, so just write:

```
<script>
```

---

Additionally, you have two `<body>` start tags. Only one of them has an `onload` attribute. Browsers may parse the first one and then ignore the second one.

---

These (among some other errors) would have been picked up by a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `"` at:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
```

Make sure you put the `"` in front of `>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

And as [Quentin notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971102/1252742), you have two `body` tags.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am dumbfounded as to how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

```
type="text/javascript" //add a " at the end
```

Correction

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Thank you Daguru! Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dungeons and Dwarves</title>
<script>
function begin()
{
    alert("Welcome to Dungeons and Dwarves! A free 'Choose Your Own Adventure' game. In this adventure, you will be faced with many decisions, some of which could potentially lead to your death. If you are willing to put your life on the line, and leap forward into a new world and explore the unexplored, press OK to begin.")
    var myAge = prompt("How old are you, adventurer?")
    if (myAge < 18)
    {
        alert("Oh! They start younger and younger every year! You'll be careful out there, wont you?")
    }
    else
    {
    alert("I see you have had some experience with adventures! I wish you the best of luck, not that you will need it!")
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='javascript:begin()'></body>
</html>
```

You are missing `"` at:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
```

You have misplaces the `<body>` tag at line number 2: remove body tag from there.

You need to include your `<title>` tag in `<head>` tag.

Comment: @downvoter reason for down voting will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
```

would be
  `<script type="text/javascript">`

and    `<body onload='javascript:begin()'></body>` 
would be
 `<body onload='javascript:begin();'></body>`

all your alerts need to end like

`var myAge = prompt("How old are you, adventurer?");`